# MySQL HA and Magento DB

Tags: mysql, high-availability

Is it possible to use MySQL cluster for Magento DB? I have Web app developed in Magento E-commerce platform and I want to make DB highly available using the MySQL cluster. Magento supports only InnoDB database engine and MySQL HA uses it's own engine NDB.

The Percona XtraDB Cluster, Does it change the InnoDB storage engine to XtraDB? Can I rollback to the MySQL native replication from Percona XtraDB Cluster?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL HA Solutions](http://serverfault.com/questions/416924/mysql-ha-solutions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out my answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/361328/mysql-cluster-for-drupal/361346#361346) for the MySQL Cluster use case (and alternatives to it). In general, MySQL Cluster is not suitable for web applications.

Cheers